# Angular App looks different after deployment (ng build)

Tags: angular, deployment, build, angular-material

I am using Angular the last few years but only tried using Angular material components in my latest project. Finally happy with my layout and go to push to production and the components (including fonts) appear about 10 to 20 times bigger after I deploy. The CSS is being picked up as the colors of the various components are reflective of the attributes I set in style.css. I have tried a couple of different calls of ng build but result is the same. I am using Angular 11, developing in Windows 10 and deploying to a linux machine. Anyone with knowledge of resolving similar issues or troubleshooting tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: it sounds you have unset fonts and font sizes in your based CSS. This issue is unlikely related to angular but to your styles

Comment: make sure you have added the fonts either to index and or angular.json file https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The fonts just didn't render as they did in development.  I ended up disabling font optimization in angular.json detailed at https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#fonts-optimization-options

under architect.build.options:

```
 "build": {
      "options": {
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": []
        },
        "scripts": [],
        "optimization": {
          "fonts": false // disable font optimization 
        }
      },
```